# Intuition about matrix exponential.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to understand matrix exponential.

My books definition:

If B is a matrix, then $e^{B}$ can be calculated with the Taylor expansion
$$I+B+\frac{B^2}{2!}+\frac{B^3}{3!}...\ (1)$$

You can also calculate, if B is 3X3-matrix, it with the formula
$$e^B=X\begin{pmatrix}e^{\lambda_1}&0&0\\0&e^{\lambda_2}&0\\0&0&e^{\lambda_3}\end{pmatrix}X^{-1}\ (2)$$
where the column vectors of X are the eigenvectors belonging to B:s eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$.

My thoughts:

(1) If B is a diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&c\end{pmatrix}$
$$e^B=\begin{pmatrix}e^a&0&0\\0&e^b&0\\0&0&e^c\end{pmatrix}$$
But if B has terms outside of the diagonal, what does it mean? e.g.
If
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}a&1&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&c\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B^2=\begin{pmatrix}a^2&a+b&0\\0&b^2&0\\0&0&c^2\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B^3=\begin{pmatrix}a^3&a^2+ab+b^2&0\\0&b^3&0\\0&0&c^3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B^4=\begin{pmatrix}a^4&a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3&0\\0&b^4&0\\0&0&c^4\end{pmatrix}$$
$$I+B+\frac{B^2}{2!}+\frac{B^3}{3!}...=\begin{pmatrix}e^a&P(a,b)&0\\0&e^b&0\\0&0&e^c\end{pmatrix}$$
where
$$P(a,b)=1+a+b+ab+a^2+b^2+a^2b+ab^2+b^3...=?$$

Since $e^x,x\in R$ is a function with the same derivative as the functions value, can we say something similar about $e^B$?

(2) It looks like $e^B\vec{v}$ expresses any vector $\vec{v}$ in the base of the eigenvectors $(X^{-1}\vec{v})$ of the matrix B, then scale each eigenvector by $e^{\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is its eigenvalue
$$\begin{pmatrix}e^{\lambda_1}&0&0\\0&e^{\lambda_2}&0\\0&0&e^{\lambda_3}\end{pmatrix}X^{-1}\vec{v}$$
then trasform back in to the original basis
$$X\begin{pmatrix}e^{\lambda_1}&0&0\\0&e^{\lambda_2}&0\\0&0&e^{\lambda_3}\end{pmatrix}X^{-1}\vec{v}$$
Am I to think of $e^B$ as scaling eigenvectors by $e^{\lambda}$?

Comment: Regarding 1, are you aware of [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)? Regarding 2, that is correct.

Comment: I am not aware of Jordan canonical form. But I will aim to be now :) Thank you

Comment: Another definition for matrix exponential would be: The differential equation $\mathbf{x}'(t) = A\mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_0$ has solution $\mathbf{x}(t) = e^{tA}\mathbf{x}_0$

Comment: @GEdgar in that definition does A need to be a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @ErikEriksson No, that is for any square matrix:  real values, complex values, diagonalizable, not diagonalizable...  Even for bounded operator on infinite-dimensional Banach space.